# How to enable delete button while deleting a rule in Application Overlay?

Tags: pega

I want to delete a rule from Application Overlay. İ have deleted all AOM ruleset versions that contains the rule to be deleted. Despite this when i open the AO menu to delete the rule, i see the delete button is disabled. 
I think this is because pyNewRuleInLP has value and not null. How can I set this property to null to enable the delete button or any other method to do this?

Comment: Could you share the screenshot of the rule ?

Comment: Should I share the ss of the AO menu which has the disabled delete button? Otherwise all instances of the rule were deleted. By the way the rule is an offer flow.